# Abrir o keyboard em list - React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Estou tentando implementar um bate-papo no meu aplicativo, mas quando abro o teclado para iniciar uma conversa, a conversa é liberada da exibição.

Aqui está o meu código e um gif do que está acontecendo.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ListView, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import Conversation from '../services/conversation';
import Imagens from '../../../imagens';


class Chat extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      conversationHistory: [],
      mensagem: ''
    };

    this.sendMessage('oi');
  }

  sendMessage(text) {
    this.setState({
      mensagem: ''
    });

    Conversation.message({
      text
    }).then(r => {
      if (r != null && r !== undefined) {
        r.data_iteracao = new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes();
        this.state.conversationHistory.push(r);
        this.setState({
          conversationHistory: this.state.conversationHistory
        });
      }
    });
  }

  renderRow(texto) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <View style={[{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }]}>
          <View style={[styles.balloon, { alignItems: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: '#dbf5b4', elevation: 1, padding: 5, borderRadius: 8 }]}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: '#000', }}>{texto.input.text}</Text>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: '#000' }}>{texto.data_iteracao}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={[{ alignItems: 'flex-start', borderRadius: 20 }]}>
          <View style={[styles.balloon, { alignItems: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7', elevation: 1, padding: 5, borderRadius: 8 }]}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: '#000' }}>{texto.output.text}</Text>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: '#000' }}>{texto.data_iteracao}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View >
      </View >
    );
  }

  render() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ListView
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.conversationHistory)}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          renderScrollComponent={props => <ScrollView {...props} />}
          onEndReachedThreshold={10}
          ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
          onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
            this.listView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
          }} />


        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="digite a mensagem..."
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value={this.state.mensagem}
              onChangeText={(mensagem) => this.setState({ mensagem })} />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSend} onPress={() => this.sendMessage(this.state.mensagem)}>
            <Image source={Imagens.send} style={styles.iconSend} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }

}

export default connect()(Chat);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  list: {
    paddingHorizontal: 17,
  },
  footer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    padding: 5,
  },
  btnSend: {
    backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 360,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  iconSend: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    height: 40,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  inputs: {
    height: 40,
    marginLeft: 16,
    borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
    flex: 1,
  },
  balloon: {
    maxWidth: 250,
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  itemIn: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  },
  itemOut: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  },
  time: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    margin: 15,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#808080'
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    borderRadius: 300,
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    marginTop: 5
  },
});
```

Comment: Acredito que toda vez que seu componente muda de estado, automaticamente vc perde o focus do input.

Tente utilizar: 
autoFocus = true e ver como se comporta, caso funcione pode implementar sua logica de como salvar este no state do componente manipula-lo.

Percebi tbm que esta utilizando value = state....
quando vc define o value do component, este nao mudara, recomendo utilizar defaultValue em vez deste, talvez esta tbm lhe ajude quando digitar algo e o valor do input mudará.

Comment: @CaioKoiti obrigado pelo retorno, mas eu não preciso de um valor inicial pro meu input e o valor é alterado no onChangeText. Meu problema é que a conversação é enviada pra cima com o Scroll, mas não há componentes abaixo suficientes pra se comportar desta forma. Grato.

Comment: Tente entao deixar sua view ou seu input como position absolute ou sobre a view da conversa.